# Python string 'converting' after inserting into a dictionary

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7

I am getting a non english text,when I am appending it to a dictionary its generating **"\xe0\xa6\xb9\xe0\xa6\xb0\xe0\xa6\x"** like text.

```
Example:
obj = {}
title = 'non english text'
print "title ...",title
obj['title'] = title
print obj
```

its returning:

```
    title... non english text
   {'title': '\xe0\xa6\xb9\xe0\xa6\'}
```

Any idea,How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: what do you mean by 'fix' you mean translate it? you want to change the encoding? what?

Comment: I mean I want like {'title':'non english text'} not like {'title': '\xe0\xa6\xb9\xe0\xa6\'}

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at UTF-8 encoded data:

```
>>> '\xe0\xa6\xb9\xe0\xa6\xb0'.decode('utf8')
u'\u09b9\u09b0'
>>> print '\xe0\xa6\xb9\xe0\xa6\xb0'.decode('utf8')
হর
```

To decode it to Unicode text use `.decode('utf8')`. If you printed that string directly to the terminal and your terminal is configured to handle UTF-8, it'll display those characters decoded for you, but the `dict` representation shows python literal representations for data contained.

Please, please, do read the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) and [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @MikeCorcoran: because printing a UTF-8 bytestring to a terminal that is configured for UTF-8 will result in a legible string. It's still UTF-8 data, and the dict literal representation shows the original bytestring as a python string literal.

Comment: Now I am getting 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)' after encoing it using decode('utf8')

Comment: @arnold: That's print itself, not the decode failing. Try `print repr(text.decode('utf8'))` for example. Note the *encode* in the exception name, encoding back failed. The Unicode HOWTO explains more.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unicode handling error. In [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html) all `text` is `unicode` - give it a go, your example in the non-ascii character set should work and you'll save yourself some headaches.

If you're stuck on Python 2.x pay attention to what Martijn is saying - he's bang on.